Understanding Thread Dump
I have Spring Boot 3 application which recently stops being responsive after few hours of uptime, I took a thread dump and all of ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker stack trace look like this
"ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2" #79 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=8662597.78ms elapsed=13618.27s tid=0x00007f6fc401e190 nid=0x773 runnable  [0x00007f7130510000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(java.base@17.0.13/SSLEngine.java:524)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000733a31ef8> (a java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.shutdown(SSLSocketChannel.java:381)
    - locked <0x000000073aed60d0> (a oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.write(SSLSocketChannel.java:242)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:211)

Does this mean I have a deadlock ?
Not sure how to undrestand the following lines
Does thread want to park itself, because it's wants to wait for some other thread?
How to find 0x0000000733a31ef8? I don't see such thread in thread dump
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(java.base@17.0.13/SSLEngine.java:524)
- parking to wait for  <0x0000000733a31ef8> (a java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool)


0x0000000733a31ef8 - is not a thread id, its a reference, in this case its a java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool

Reference for Understanding the thread dump : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/using_threaddumps.html
This thread is one of many worker threads in Java's common thread pool. Right now, it's paused, waiting for something from the pool while trying to establish a secure connection. It's been waiting for over 4 hours, which suggests it might be stuck or delayed due to network problems or issues with the thread pool itself.
Please refer your implementation for the configuration changes like network timeouts and check if the remote server is currently up and running healthy.

It's paused ? java.lang.Thread.State is RUNNABLE.
How to find on what the thread is waiting for ?
